# Convert string to DateTime in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, string-formatting

I have data that on the server is in the form of a `smalldatetime` but when I return this data to my application it gets returned to me as a `string`.  This happens for a variety of reasons that don't apply to this question.

What I am trying to do is when this data gets populated in my DataGridView I need to format it as a `datetime` with just the date no time in the format '`mm/dd/yyyy`'. I have tried the following but the data remains in the format of '`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm`':

```
this.DataGridView.Columns[7].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";
```

How can I format this column of data?

Comment: Did you try this:

    this.DataGridView.Columns[7].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy"; ?

Comment: Are you sure your date is a `DateTime` (and not a string) when it enters your dataridview? What you say suggests not.

Comment: @GertArnold as I said the data in the server is a datetime but it is a string when I get it in my application. I need to convert the string back to a datetime format for display

Comment: I know, but your `Format` is meant for the opposite: `DateTime` to `String`, or do you convert the string data before populating the grid?

Comment: the data is a string prior to populating the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Column.DefaultCellStyle.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) property or set it [in designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95y5fz2x.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.CELLSTYLEDIALOG%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)

or

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM'/'dd'/'yyyy";
```

or

You can set the format you want:

```
dataGridViewCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
this.date.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle;
// date being a System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

you can do like this....

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // If the column is the Artist column, check the
    // value.
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Artist")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            // Check for the string "pink" in the cell.
            string stringValue = (string)e.Value;
            stringValue = stringValue.ToLower();
            if ((stringValue.IndexOf("pink") > -1))
            {
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
            }

        }
    }
    else if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Release Date")
    {
        ShortFormDateFormat(e);
    }
}

//Even though the date internaly stores the year as YYYY, using formatting, the
//UI can have the format in YY.  
private static void ShortFormDateFormat(DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs formatting)
{
    if (formatting.Value != null)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder dateString = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            DateTime theDate = DateTime.Parse(formatting.Value.ToString());

            dateString.Append(theDate.Month);
            dateString.Append("/");
            dateString.Append(theDate.Day);
            dateString.Append("/");
            dateString.Append(theDate.Year.ToString().Substring(2));
            formatting.Value = dateString.ToString();
            formatting.FormattingApplied = true;
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            // Set to false in case there are other handlers interested trying to
            // format this DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs instance.
            formatting.FormattingApplied = false;
        }
    }
}
```

would you pls go through this link for [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx)

Comment: Neither are working. the data is still being displayed with date and time.

Comment: My datagrid is bound after I return my data.  DataBindingSource.DataSource = DataSet.vwMyView;

Answer (score 0):

For C++/CLI:

> Exemple: 12.12.20 12:13:01

```
System::String^ format = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm::ss";

dataGridView_Archive->Columns[1]->DefaultCellStyle->Format = format;
```